# Why isn't my code detecting elements in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, automation, instagram

I'm trying to automate Instagram. My code works when logging in, after that, it detects nothing. All I'm trying to do is hit the search button, and it wont detect it. I tried finding element by CSS selector, class and xpath and nothing is working.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

Username = ""
Password = ""

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url="https://www.instagram.com/")

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input'))).send_keys(f"{Username}")

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input'))).send_keys(f"{Password}")

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div'))).click()

//Code stops working after this

WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'_//*[@id="mount_0_0_YP"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/div'))).click()

print("Pass")
```

Comment: you used full xpath and it may be changed. BEcuase such instagram, google, amazon etc applications change their source code attributes frequently to prevent automation. probably that's why not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Are you trying to click the below 'Search' button?**

[image]

**If yes, change your XPath expression to below:**

`//div[contains(@class,'_aacl _aacp _aacu _aacx _aada') and contains(text(),'Search')]`

**This XPath expression will locate the Search element(see below):**

[image]

Comment: so like this? Things = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[contains(@class,'_aacl _aacp _aacu _aacx _aada') and contains(text(),'Search')]")

Comment: Change 'By.CSS_SELECTOR' to 'By.XPATH'

Comment: So I changed it to Things = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"div[contains(@class,'_aacl _aacp _aacu _aacx _aada') and contains(text(),'Search')]")
and it still says "no symbol found"

Comment: You have missed '//' before 'div'

Comment: Yay it worked. Can you help me understand how you knew that was what you were needing?

Comment: Accept the answer if it has resolved your question. The Xpath expression I gave you locates the Search button.

Comment: ALWAYS avoid long expressions like this `/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/div/` ESPECIALLY using array notation. INSTEAD, use well-defined, specific predicates like the one Shawn provided in this answer.